# How to add value in map of map?

Tags: apex, map

I am trying to add map of map values, I have to intialize the map key first and then try to add value later. Below is the exact logic i am trying to achieve.

```
Map<string,Map<string,List<string>>> finalMap = new Map<string,Map<string,List<string>>>();

Map<string,List<string>> subMap = new Map<string,List<string>>();
submap.put('One',new list<string>{'One','TWO'});

finalMap.put('SUB1',new Map<string,List<string>>());

//Do some logics and finally try to add the values with the key

finalmap.get('SUB1').put(subMap); //Error as stated below

System.debug(finalmap);
```

> ERROR :Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   `[Map<String,List<String>>].put(Map<String,List<String>>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a map onto existing map, use `putAll()` method.

```
finalMap.get('DETAILS').putAll(subDetails);
```

It will add the entries of `subDetails` onto whatever Map `finalMap` contains aganist key *'DETAILS'*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add like below

```
finalMap.put('DETAILS',subDetails);
```

OR

Get the existing value and den update it like below

```
Map<string,List<string>> subDetails= finalMap .get('DETAILS')
//-- Do your business logic to update subDetails and then add as below
finalMap.put('DETAILS',subDetails);
```